# How to get the list of already set reminders which are due today

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-sdk-2.3

I have set reminders to trigger 3 times everyday using AlarmManager class in android.
Reminders are getting triggered correctly.
I want to show the list of reminders which are due for today.
I am saving timings (not their dates) in my database.
How can I go about it?

Comment: So, you want to show list of alarms that will be triggered today, correct?